# Read raw color data from PHP's .gd or .gd2 format?

Tags: php, image, colors, gd, gd2

In another question I saw some source, that would export an image into .gd or .gd2 format and then read raw pixel color data from the generated source.

Is this possible? Where can I find more information about these formats, or any other, that generates a raw pixel color data sequence of some sort?

My final goal is quite simple actually. I would like to read the color data of all pixels of an image (say 1000px by 1000px), without having to call `imagecolorat` a gazillion times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible. I've used the technique in a project. What [the code](https://code.google.com/p/flaczki/source/browse/trunk/flaczki/TransparentJPEGConverter.php) does is add alpha channel information from a separate to an image. Something dead simple, but would be insanely slow using imagecolorat() and imagesetpixel().

The data is a read bear to work with. The image is divided into tiles, so getting the pixel at a given set of coordinates is a little tricky.

The information about the format came entirely from looking at the source code. I don't believe there's any other documentation.

The difficulty of directly manipulating pixels in standard PHP was the motivation behind the creation of the [QB extension](http://www.php-qb.net). It lets you do this kind of work at much more reasonable speed. Normalization of pixels into floating point vectors also simplifies calculation a great deal. Might be worth your while to look into.

Comment: You have no idea how much I needed this solution and how helpful is this for me! THANK YOU!!!